# Les efforts physiques auxquels j’avais consenti ou Les efforts[…]que j’avais consenti à faire?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

1-Ma blessure est survenue après les efforts physiques que j’avais consenti à faire

2-Ma blessure est survenue après les efforts physiques auxquels j’avais consenti.

Consentir au sens de « donner son accord, promettre de, convenir de, accepter de»

N’hésitez pas à me donner d’autres propositions si l’inspiration est au rendez-vous et que vous les jugez meilleures.

Merci.

Comment: Je me suis blessé après avoir consenti de faire certains efforts physiques. [?] [la blessure est arrivée me fait penser aux transports....:)]

Comment: Je suis de ton avis, j’ai remplacé le verbe « arriver » par le verbe « survenir », c’est plus joli. Concernant ta proposition, il me semble que l’on consent à quelque chose, sinon rien à redire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La première phrase de la question me semble préférable si l'on doit conserver le verbe *consentir*.

Si ce n'est pas le cas, je suggérerais la suivante:

> Ma blessure est la conséquence d'efforts physiques auxquels je m'étais astreint.

Answer (score 0):

« Consentir » se construit d'habitude avec « à » (LBU § 906). La même section avertit que dans la langue littéraire « de » subsiste.

> Consentir de subsiste (cf. § 904, H) dans la langue littéraire :
> ♦ Quelques esprits distingués n'ont consenti DE voir en ce drame que l'exposé d'un cas bizarre.  (GIDE, Immor., Préf.)
> ♦Je consens D'être le parrain (SCHLUMBERGER, Fils Louveigné, 1,9).
> ♦ La grandeur, pour se faire reconnaître, doit trop souvent consentir D'imiter la grandeur. (J. ROSTAND, Pens. d'un
> bioL, p. 163)
> ♦ Sur une terre qu'il ne consent jamais DE laisser écraser. (Cl. ROY, dans les
> Lettres françaises, 31 janv. 1947)
> ♦ Tous les écrivains célèbres [...] ont consenti DE poser pour elle [= une photographe].  (M. CHAPELAN, dans le Figaro litt., 17 août 1970)Etc.

- 1/ Il avait été proposé que toute l'équipe suive pendant quelques temps un entrainement plus dur, mais le choix de refuser des exercices supplémentaires était laissé à chacun des joueurs ; j'avais accepté, ayant jugé cela plutôt utile. La blessure est survenue après les efforts physiques que  j’avais consenti à faire.

Selon le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/consentir?page=1) la construction transitive (« transitive directe » dans le TLFi)  ne convient pas puisque le verbe signifie alors « concéder, accorder » (**I. 2.**) ; cette construction correspond à « A.− Emploi trans. dir. Consentir qqc. Autoriser, permettre. »  dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consentir).  noter que tous les exemples fournis par le dictionnaire de l'Académie sont construits avec « à » (**II**).

> **I.** V. tr.
> **1.** Class. Admettre comme certain. Une vérité consentie par tous, unanimement consentie.
> **2.** Concéder ; accorder. Consentir une faveur, un avantage à quelqu'un.
> ♦ Je consens que vous soyez présent à l'entretien.
> ♦ *commerce*. Consentir un rabais, une remise sur un article.
> ♦ *droit*. Consentir une vente. Un ajournement consenti par les deux parties.
> ♦ *milit*. Consentir un armistice au vaincu.
> **II.** V. intr.
> Donner son accord, son adhésion à ; ne pas s'opposer à. J'y consens de grand cœur. Il a consenti à cette séparation. Il a consenti à cette alliance, mais sans l'approuver. Ils ont consenti à rencontrer la partie adverse. Il consent à présenter des excuses. Absolt. Elle n'a consenti qu'à regret. Prov. Qui ne dit mot consent.

Noter aussi que tous les exemples dans le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/consentir) sont construits avec « à ».

Comment: La phrase que tu as mis après le 1/, est presque la même que celui du PO. Curieux, n'est-pas?

Comment: @Lambie En quoi est-ce curieux ? Peut-être parce que ça n'apporte pas de nouveauté ? Le but est surtout de préciser le contexte d'utilisation du verbe.

Comment: D'où vient la phrase?

Comment: @Lambie Assez souvent j'utilise des phrases qui me viennent à l'esprit, des concoctions personnelles ; c'en est une.